# Почему не изменяется scroll?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет. При загрузке страницы, scroll должен сразу же сам изменять свое положение на `500px` от top'a. Почему не работает?

```
mounted(){
    window.scrollY = 500;
},
```

Отредактировано:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `window.scrollTo(0, 500)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что у Вас список рендерится через `v-for` никак не влияет, в этом есть смысл `nextTick`, что "любые" действия будут выполнены после следующего обновления DOM.

```
data() {
    return {
        list: []
    };
},

async created() {
    // Получаете Ваш список с API
    this.$data.list = await makeApiCall().getList();
    // Дожидаемся следующего `DOM update`
    await this.$nextTick();
    // Прокручиваем документ с указанными координатами
    scrollTo(0, 500);
}
```

Можно и без `async + await`:

```
data() {
    return {
        list: []
    };
},

created() {
    makeApiCall().then((list) => {
        this.$data.list = list;

        this.$nextTick().then(() => {
            scrollTo(0, 500);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Ну вот посмотрите на мой код, что я сделал не так?

Comment: @Евгений `then((response) => { this.contents = response.data; this.$nextTick().then(() => scroll(0, 500)); }`, `nextTick` вызывается после мутации данных, а не в разных частях кода, тем более в разных `lifecycle events`

Answer (score 0):

scrollY — свойство только для чтения.
Используй window.scrollTo(0, 500);
Функция выполняет то же, что и window.scroll

Если нужна гарантия что все элементы отрисовались то используй

```
mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(() => window.scroll(0, 500))
},
```

Comment: Ну вот я вставил этот код на страницу, но ничего не происходит... Загружается как обычно, scroll не изменяет свою позицию. У меня рендерится список записей через v-for это может влиять?